# Cocoa Drag and Drop doesn't work the first time app is launched

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I've an `NSTableView` and an `NSOutlineView` in my app. The user should be able to drag an item from the outline view to the table view; if it's an acceptable operation (i.e. the selected rows indices are in the pasteboard) then the table view's destination row lights up. Everything works except for when the item(s) are initially dragged into the table view.

Each `NSTableCellView` in the receiving table has these methods:

```
func dragContainsIndices(pasteboard: NSPasteboard) -> IndexSet {
        if let types:[String] = pasteboard.types {
            for type in types {
                if type == BTVPBoardType { //_1
                    if let indexData: Data = pasteboard.data(forType: BTVPBoardType) {. //_2
                        let indicies: IndexSet = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: indexData) as! IndexSet
                        if indicies.count > 0 {
                            return indicies
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return IndexSet()
    }

override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        let pastboard: NSPasteboard = sender.draggingPasteboard()
        if self.dragContainsIndices(pasteboard: pastboard).count > 0 {
            self.backingIcon.imageColour = .darkGreen //proprietary background colouring method
        }
        return  .link
    }
```

If the user tries to drag row(s) from the outline view to the table view then the `draggingEntered(_:)` in the table cell view runs but `dragContainsIndices(_:)` doesn't recognise the `NSPasteboard` as having any data even though it contains the correct `type`. The check at `//_1` passes but then the code finds no data. So it returns an empty set which causes the background colour not to be changed.

Without releasing anything, if the user drags the item off the cell and then back on to it then the index set will unwrap correctly and the colour will change.

In the `NSTableView` I provide the drag session with theses methods:

```
override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
        let mouseDown    = self.mouseDownEvent.locationInWindow
        let dragPoint    = event.locationInWindow
        let dragDistance = hypot(mouseDown.x - dragPoint.x, mouseDown.y - dragPoint.y)

        if dragDistance < 3 || self.selectedRowIndexes.count < 1 {
            return
        }

        let pboardItem: NSPasteboardItem = NSPasteboardItem()
        if pboardItem.setDataProvider(self, forTypes: [BTVPBoardType]) {
            Swift.print ("Set data")
        }
        let dragItem: NSDraggingItem = NSDraggingItem(pasteboardWriter: pboardItem)
        var dragPos = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        dragImage = NSImage.init(named: NSImageNameMultipleDocuments)!
        dragPos.x += dragImage.size.width
        dragPos.y += dragImage.size.height
        dragItem.imageComponentsProvider = {
            let component = NSDraggingImageComponent(key: NSDraggingImageComponentIconKey)
            component.contents = self.dragImage
            component.frame = NSRect(origin: NSPoint(), size: self.dragImage.size)
            return [component]
        }
        beginDraggingSession(with: [dragItem], event: event, source: self)
    }

func pasteboard(_ pasteboard: NSPasteboard?, item: NSPasteboardItem, provideDataForType type: String) {
        if files.count < 1 {return} //don't bother if there's no 
        if let pasteboard = pasteboard {
            pasteboard.declareTypes([BTVPBoardType], owner: self)
            let _: Int = pasteboard.clearContents()
            let indices = self.selectedRowIndexes
            pasteboard.setData(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: indices), forType: BTVPBoardType)
            Swift.print("written objects") //always writes indices
        }
    }
```

Is the `pasteboard(_ pasteboard: NSPasteboard?, item: NSPasteboardItem, provideDataForType type: String)` is it something to do with lazy fetching? For some reason I am having a bit of a head block with drag and dropping on Mac.

Comment: Documentation of `NSPasteboard`s `dataForType:`: "This method may also return nil if the pasteboard server cannot supply the data in time".

Comment: Thanks for that. I've just tried wrapping a single index into the pasteboard to check if it's because I'm not responding in time but it makes no difference.

Comment: You are on the right track, though: I've just done a hack that works. In `dragContainsIndices` I check twice for `pasteboard.data`. The first time fails but the second one passes.

Comment: Why do you use `setDataProvider` instead of `setData`?

Comment: I can't remember if I've tried that in one of the many incarnations the code went through. I think I remember it being to facilitate lazy data fetching.

Comment: Lazy data fetching of `self.selectedRowIndexes`?

Comment: No, a more general lazy data fetching for the drag and drop session - I seem to remember that being good practice, but I know my comprehension of this subject is hazy, for no apparent reason. I will try just the more direct ’setData’ as soon as I get back - I am only passing an array of int's.

Comment: @Willeke that worked. I should have tried it sooner! Put your comment as an answer and I'll mark it up.